# Genearate Custom gereator value using Spring boot data JPA postgresql DataBase

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using JAVA , Spring boot , Spring data JPA and Postgresql Database .
Trying to generate a custom String value for empid column .
like emp1, emp2 , emp3 ... etc

But not able to create the values .
facing issue : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column employee_seq.next_val does not exist
Position: 9

`@Id @Column(name = "employee_id") @GenericGenerator(name = "emp_id_gen", strategy = "com.sanketdd.generator.utility.EmployeeEdGenerator") @GeneratedValue(generator = "emp_id_gen" , strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) private String employeeId;`

`
public class EmployeeEdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

```
@Override
public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) {
    String  prefix ="EMP";
    String suffix="";
    String finalVal = null;
    try {

        Connection connection= sharedSessionContractImplementor.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        String sql = " select employee_seq.next_val from  employee_seq";
        ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()){
            Long value=rs.getLong(1);
            suffix=value.toString();
        }

        finalVal=prefix+suffix;

        System.out.println("Final value is "+ finalVal);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return finalVal ;
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is wrong in PostgreSQL. Use [nextval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) function like this:

```sql
String sql = "select nextval('employee_seq')";
```